# how to store information related of a pin in MKPinAnnotation

Tags: web-services, ios, mkannotation

actually, i have retrieved a lot of informations about service stations from web-service, they are here, i displayed for each Station a pin annotation to show it on the Map with a `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`, now i want to store for each pin some additional informations like :

```
float lng = [[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_longitude"] floatValue];//that's how i retrieve it from web-service
float lat = [[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_latitude"] floatValue];//that's how i retrieve it from web-service
```

for my purpose, i use this well known method of the delegate :

```
 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
        NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped");
//how to do to store additional informations

    }
```

but i am some kind blocked, how can i store additional informations related to each pin, help please, any suggestions, sample code, tutorials will be appreciated :))))) thx in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what the difficulty is.  Don't you have a custom class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol?  In calloutAccessoryControlTapped, you can access the annotation using view.annotation.

Comment: Hi, i have a class named MyLocation which implement the MKAnnotation protocol, should i declare in `MyLocation.h` file all properties that i would display in the detail view, if so, how can i assign and get values, in other words, how can i read it in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method ? thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, declare all your properties in MyLocation.h (the class that implements MKAnnotation).  When creating annotations and before calling `addAnnotation`, set the properties.

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, get the properties like this (example uses properties in MyLocation defined in your previous question):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    MyLocation *myLoc = (MyLocation *)view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: enseigneDeLaStation = %@, distanceVersLaStation=%@", myLoc.enseigneDeLaStation, myLoc.distanceVersLaStation);
}
```

Comment: Hi Anna, please, in this method (`calloutAccessoryControlTapped`), i am trying to move the user to another view where he will be able to see the details, so i do this `[self  presentModalViewController:detailStation animated:YES];`however, i see a white screen although `detailStation` is declared and connected in IB, can you help me there ? thx in advance :)

Comment: You should ask that as a new question and include the complete code in calloutAccessoryControlTapped, show how and where detailStation is declared in code and how exactly it is connected in IB, etc.

Comment: Hi, this is my new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954920/white-screen-when-i-click-on-uibuttontypedetaildisclosure